# Api Vk отправка поста в группу, сначала картинка потом текст

Tags: php, веб-программирование, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Есть рабочая форма с сайта отправки постов в группу. Отправляю картинку и текст, но при публикации вк в посте сначала идёт текст потом картинка, смотрится это не очень. Изучение документации результов не дало.

Answer (score 0):

Судя по [документации](https://vk.com/dev/wall.post), способа изменить расположение вложений действительно нет, да и таких постов я ни разу не видел. Как вариант - вместо постов создавать [статьи](https://vk.com/blog/longreads)(в них можно располагать вложения произвольным образом), но опять же, в данный момент я не нашел методов в api их создания.